# Is there some way to test if a date is contained in a string?

Tags: delphi

Delphi 10.4

I need to check if the last 8 or 10 characters of a string fit a date mask.  I would like to do this using only pure Delphi code.  Any ideas?

Examples of data:

Docket 05/04/98

Docket 12/11/2021

Something like

```
if DocumentName <> '' then
begin
  //* Test for date as part of the document name and remove it if it is.
  if IsDateMask(RStr(DocumentName,8),'00|/00|/00',-1) then
    DocumentName := Copy(DocumentName,1,length(DocumentName)-9)

  else
    if IsDateMask(RStr(DocumentName,10),'00|/00|/0000',-1) then
      DocumentName := Copy(DocumentName,1,length(DocumentName)-11);

  ...
end;
```

Comment: It look simple string parsing to me. Iterate from the end of string, counting the digits and separators and then validate the values. Don't forget the data format may be different in different countries. You should at least try to write your code, edit your question with it and explain what problem you have (This website is not a code writing service. We will be happy to help you with coding issues you have).

Comment: Think about if you only want to detect theoretical dates (`2/29/2003` and `0/55/72` wouldn't be legal). And expect [US (m/d/yyyy) versus UK (dd/mm/yyyy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country). The delimiter is also important (i.e. `d.m.yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd`).

Comment: The question is: April, 5th or may, 4th? ;)

Comment: @StefanGlienke Trekki or Jedi? ;-p

Comment: [TryStrToDate](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToDate).

Comment: You can use `TRegEx.Match` to extract the value

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use TRegEx to extract date value :

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  RegularExpressions,
  Classes;

var
  List: TStringList;
  s: string;
  Value: string;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;

  try
    List.Add('Docket 05/04/98');
    List.Add('Docket none');
    List.Add('Docket 12/11/2021');
    List.Add('Docket 01/2021');

    for s in List do
    begin
      Value := TRegEx.Match(s, '\d{2}\D\d{2}\D(\d{4}|\d{2})').Value;
      Writeln(Format('StringValue=%s', [s]));
      Writeln(Format('DateValue=%s', [Value]));
      Writeln('------------------------------------------');
    end;

    Readln;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(List);
  end;
end.
```

Output value will be :

```
StringValue=Docket 05/04/98
DateValue=05/04/98
------------------------------------------
StringValue=Docket none
DateValue=
------------------------------------------
StringValue=Docket 12/11/2021
DateValue=12/11/2021
------------------------------------------
StringValue=Docket 01/2021
DateValue=
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: In that case I'd use one regex for both cases right away: `\d{2}\D\d{2}\D(\d{4}|\d{2})` - as it stands now your first regex will find `12/11/20` on the second text.

Comment: I agree, I edit with a list and output result. Thanks!